# Why does Tone JS not play nice in a Svelte component?

Tags: javascript, rollupjs, svelte, svelte-component

I am fairly new to Svelte (I'm using version 2 until 3 is properly released) and I'm building a site that aims to do some audio analysis (FFT). I'm therefore incorporating the venerable ToneJS library (http://tonejs.github.io/) into one of my Components.

For some reason, merely importing ToneJS is enough to crash the whole application.

Here is the entirety of my Svelte Component:

```
<h2>Pitch analyser</h2>


<script>
    import Tone from 'tone';

</script>
```

This causes the error:

```
Tone.js:7 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'listener' of object '#<AudioContext>'
at t.Context.set (Tone.js:7)
at t.Listener.<anonymous> (Tone.js:7)
at Function.e.getContext (Tone.js:7)
at new t.Listener (Tone.js:7)
at Object.<anonymous> (Tone.js:7)
at Object.<anonymous> (Tone.js:7)
at i (Tone.js:1)
at Object.<anonymous> (Tone.js:7)
at i (Tone.js:1)
at Tone.js:1
```

It's possible that this is not specific to Svelte, but I've used Tone JS successfully in many other projects (including inside React, etc.) without any trouble.

What could be causing this? And how to start using ToneJS inside my Svelte app? (Packaged/transpiled using Rollup)

Comment: Seems that when using webpack, this issue does not occur. So must be something in the way rollup packages ToneJS.

Comment: It seems that the problem isn't on the Rollup side.

Answer (score 4):

This is happening because Rollup, as a native JavaScript module bundler, has to treat all JS as though it were in strict mode (because JavaScript modules are always strict), even when they're converted from legacy formats.

Unfortunately Tone.js is doing things that violate strict mode (assigning to non-writable properties). I would recommend filing an issue on that repo; strict mode is faster and more secure, and there's really no reason *not* to support strict mode environments.

In the meantime, you can work around it by including Tone.js as a regular `<script>` tag and referencing it in your app as a global.

Answer (score 0):

Putting the `intro:` line in `rollup.config.js` fixed it for me:

```
output: {
    sourcemap: true,
    format: 'iife',
    name: 'app',
    file: 'public/bundle.js',
    // Added this line:
    intro: 'var global = typeof self !== undefined ? self : this;'
},
```

Answer (score 0):

**2023 Update:**

If you're trying to use Tone.js in a svelte 4 / sveltekit 1.0 project, here is one potential workaround, albeit at the cost of SSR:

Create `+layout.ts` in whatever route you're trying to use (i.e. src/routes/+layout.ts) and set:

```
export const ssr = false;
```

This should prevent Tone.js from running in node by disabling the ssr step, which is necessary because it depends on the Web Audio API.